# Sort list in ascending order in android studio (universal music player app)

Tags: android, sorting, listview, android-studio

I am using "Android universal music player" Android application and I want to sort music list in ascending order right now audios are showing randomly I tried multiple example but it that don't work for me please help me if any once can as high poverty.

```
public class MediaBrowserFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = LogHelper.makeLogTag(MediaBrowserFragment.class);

    private static final String ARG_MEDIA_ID = "media_id";

    private BrowseAdapter mBrowserAdapter;
    private String mMediaId;
    private MediaFragmentListener mMediaFragmentListener;
    private View mErrorView, HyperLinkView;
    private TextView mErrorMessage, HyperLink;
    public Spanned Text;
    private final BroadcastReceiver mConnectivityChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        private boolean oldOnline = false;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // We don't care about network changes while this fragment is not associated
            // with a media ID (for example, while it is being initialized)
            if (mMediaId != null) {
                boolean isOnline = NetworkHelper.isOnline(context);
                if (isOnline != oldOnline) {
                    oldOnline = isOnline;
                    checkForUserVisibleErrors(false);
                    if (isOnline) {
                        mBrowserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Receive callbacks from the MediaController. Here we update our state such as which queue
    // is being shown, the current title and description and the PlaybackState.
    private final MediaControllerCompat.Callback mMediaControllerCallback =
            new MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onMetadataChanged(MediaMetadataCompat metadata) {
            super.onMetadataChanged(metadata);
            if (metadata == null) {
                return;
            }
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "Received metadata change to media ",
                    metadata.getDescription().getMediaId());
            mBrowserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(@NonNull PlaybackStateCompat state) {
            super.onPlaybackStateChanged(state);
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "Received state change: ", state);
            checkForUserVisibleErrors(false);
            mBrowserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    private final MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback mSubscriptionCallback =
        new MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onChildrenLoaded(@NonNull String parentId,
                                         @NonNull List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> children) {
                try {
                    LogHelper.d(TAG, "fragment onChildrenLoaded, parentId=" + parentId +
                        "  count=" + children.size());
                    checkForUserVisibleErrors(children.isEmpty());
                    mBrowserAdapter.clear();
                    for (MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem item : children) {
                        mBrowserAdapter.add(item);
                    }
                    mBrowserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    LogHelper.e(TAG, "Error on childrenloaded", t);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull String id) {
                LogHelper.e(TAG, "browse fragment subscription onError, id=" + id);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.error_loading_media, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                checkForUserVisibleErrors(true);
            }
        };

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // If used on an activity that doesn't implement MediaFragmentListener, it
        // will throw an exception as expected:
        mMediaFragmentListener = (MediaFragmentListener) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "fragment.onCreateView");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        //FooterLink - Rehan
        HyperLinkView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        HyperLink = (TextView) HyperLinkView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Text = Html.fromHtml("" + "<a href='http://www.example.com/'>example</a>");

        HyperLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        HyperLink.setText(Text);
        //#FooterLink - Rehan

        mErrorView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.playback_error);
        mErrorMessage = (TextView) mErrorView.findViewById(R.id.error_message);

        mBrowserAdapter = new BrowseAdapter(getActivity());

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(mBrowserAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                checkForUserVisibleErrors(false);
                MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem item = mBrowserAdapter.getItem(position);
                mMediaFragmentListener.onMediaItemSelected(item);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // fetch browsing information to fill the listview:
        MediaBrowserCompat mediaBrowser = mMediaFragmentListener.getMediaBrowser();

        LogHelper.d(TAG, "fragment.onStart, mediaId=", mMediaId,
                "  onConnected=" + mediaBrowser.isConnected());

        if (mediaBrowser.isConnected()) {
            onConnected();
        }

        // Registers BroadcastReceiver to track network connection changes.
        this.getActivity().registerReceiver(mConnectivityChangeReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        MediaBrowserCompat mediaBrowser = mMediaFragmentListener.getMediaBrowser();
        if (mediaBrowser != null && mediaBrowser.isConnected() && mMediaId != null) {
            mediaBrowser.unsubscribe(mMediaId);
        }
        MediaControllerCompat controller = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity())
                .getSupportMediaController();
        if (controller != null) {
            controller.unregisterCallback(mMediaControllerCallback);
        }
        this.getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mConnectivityChangeReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mMediaFragmentListener = null;
    }

    public String getMediaId() {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            return args.getString(ARG_MEDIA_ID);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setMediaId(String mediaId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
        args.putString(MediaBrowserFragment.ARG_MEDIA_ID, mediaId);
        setArguments(args);
    }

    // Called when the MediaBrowser is connected. This method is either called by the
    // fragment.onStart() or explicitly by the activity in the case where the connection
    // completes after the onStart()
    public void onConnected() {
        if (isDetached()) {
            return;
        }
        mMediaId = getMediaId();
        if (mMediaId == null) {
            mMediaId = mMediaFragmentListener.getMediaBrowser().getRoot();
        }
        updateTitle();

        // Unsubscribing before subscribing is required if this mediaId already has a subscriber
        // on this MediaBrowser instance. Subscribing to an already subscribed mediaId will replace
        // the callback, but won't trigger the initial callback.onChildrenLoaded.
        //
        // This is temporary: A bug is being fixed that will make subscribe
        // consistently call onChildrenLoaded initially, no matter if it is replacing an existing
        // subscriber or not. Currently this only happens if the mediaID has no previous
        // subscriber or if the media content changes on the service side, so we need to
        // unsubscribe first.
        mMediaFragmentListener.getMediaBrowser().unsubscribe(mMediaId);

        mMediaFragmentListener.getMediaBrowser().subscribe(mMediaId, mSubscriptionCallback);

        // Add MediaController callback so we can redraw the list when metadata changes:
        MediaControllerCompat controller = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity())
                .getSupportMediaController();
        if (controller != null) {
            controller.registerCallback(mMediaControllerCallback);
        }
    }

    private void checkForUserVisibleErrors(boolean forceError) {
        boolean showError = forceError;
        // If offline, message is about the lack of connectivity:
        if (!NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            mErrorMessage.setText(R.string.error_no_connection);
            showError = true;
        } else {
            // otherwise, if state is ERROR and metadata!=null, use playback state error message:
            MediaControllerCompat controller = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity())
                    .getSupportMediaController();
            if (controller != null
                && controller.getMetadata() != null
                && controller.getPlaybackState() != null
                && controller.getPlaybackState().getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_ERROR
                && controller.getPlaybackState().getErrorMessage() != null) {
                mErrorMessage.setText(controller.getPlaybackState().getErrorMessage());
                showError = true;
            } else if (forceError) {
                // Finally, if the caller requested to show error, show a generic message:
                mErrorMessage.setText(R.string.error_loading_media);
                showError = true;
            }
        }
        mErrorView.setVisibility(showError ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "checkForUserVisibleErrors. forceError=", forceError,
            " showError=", showError,
            " isOnline=", NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity()));
    }

    private void updateTitle() {
        if (MediaIDHelper.MEDIA_ID_ROOT.equals(mMediaId)) {
            mMediaFragmentListener.setToolbarTitle(null);
            return;
        }

        MediaBrowserCompat mediaBrowser = mMediaFragmentListener.getMediaBrowser();
        mediaBrowser.getItem(mMediaId, new MediaBrowserCompat.ItemCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLoaded(MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem item) {
                mMediaFragmentListener.setToolbarTitle(
                        item.getDescription().getTitle());
            }
        });
    }

    // An adapter for showing the list of browsed MediaItem's
    private static class BrowseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> {

        public BrowseAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.media_list_item, new ArrayList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem item = getItem(position);
            int itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_NONE;
            if (item.isPlayable()) {
                itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_PLAYABLE;
                MediaControllerCompat controller = ((FragmentActivity) getContext())
                        .getSupportMediaController();
                if (controller != null && controller.getMetadata() != null) {
                    String currentPlaying = controller.getMetadata().getDescription().getMediaId();
                    String musicId = MediaIDHelper.extractMusicIDFromMediaID(
                            item.getDescription().getMediaId());
                    if (currentPlaying != null && currentPlaying.equals(musicId)) {
                        PlaybackStateCompat pbState = controller.getPlaybackState();
                        if (pbState == null ||
                                pbState.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_ERROR) {
                            itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_NONE;
                        } else if (pbState.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
                            itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_PLAYING;
                        } else {
                            itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_PAUSED;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return MediaItemViewHolder.setupView((Activity) getContext(), convertView, parent,
                item.getDescription(), itemState);
        }
    }

    public interface MediaFragmentListener extends MediaBrowserProvider {
        void onMediaItemSelected(MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem item);
        void setToolbarTitle(CharSequence title);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you can't just insert each item in place which you need in your `BrowseAdapter`

Comment: You want to sort them based on a song title or an artist name or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you call `public void onChildrenLoaded(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> children)` you first need to sort your list by using `Collections.sort()` passing to it the list to sort, and a comparator where you define by what key you want to sort the list (song name, artist name, etc).
It might look something like this:

```
Collections.sort(children, new Comparator<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem lhs, MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem rhs) {
            return lhs.getSongTitle().compareTo(rhs.getSongTitle());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to find the exact code can you give example with the above code which I menction.

Comment: @SyedHyderAli look, you have a variable called `mSubscriptionCallback` which holds a reference to an anonymous class inside which you implemented two callback methods. The first one being `onChildrenLoaded`, and the second one being `onError`. Can you show the file or code snippet where `onChildrenLoaded` gets called?
That is the place where you apply sorting to your `children` list so that inside `onChildrenLoaded` callback you can work with a list that is already sorted.

Comment: Please have a look on the below code you can find "Collections.shuffle(shuffled);" I am thinking that data getting bind here please let me know i try reverse also but that don't work for me. below is the link of source code.[link]

Comment: `//List<MediaMetadataCompat> shuffled = new ArrayList<>(mMusicListById.size()); Rehan - Org
        List<MediaMetadataCompat> shuffled = new ArrayList<>(mMusicListById.size()); //Rehan - Cnage .size to .hashCode
        for (MutableMediaMetadata mutableMetadata: mMusicListById.values()) {
            shuffled.add(mutableMetadata.metadata);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        //Collections.sort(shuffled, Collections.reverseOrder());
        //Collections.reverse(shuffled);
        return shuffled;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to sort your MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem;

```
 Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem lhs, MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem rhs) {
                return lhs.getDescription().getTitle().toString().compareTo(rhs.getDescription().getTitle().toString());
            }
        });
```

Also if you want to sort your list by other things, just type after `getDescription().blablabla.compareTo.....`